# Топология сети

Tags: сеть

Помогите дуго соображаю....
Задания:

1 Пусть IP-адрес некоторого узла подсети равен 198.65.12.67, а значение маски для этой подсети - 255.255.255.240. Определите номер подсети. Какое максимальное число узлов может быть в этой подсети?

2 Для IP-адреса 129.64.134.5 указана маска 255.255.128.0. Определите номер подсети и номер узла.

3 Номер сети, который получил администратор от поставщика услуг, - 129.44.0.0. В качестве маски было выбрано значение 255.255.192.0. Сколько подсетей может организовать администратор?

4 Маска сети: 255.255.255.248. Адрес IP: 192.168.1.219. Определите адрес сети и максимальное число сетевых устройств, которые могут быть подключены к данной сети.

1) Номер подсети 3
Под идентификатор узла отведено 4 бит 
максимальное число узлов = 2^4=16

2) номер подсети 6

3) 16 382

4) 2^5=32
адрес сети адрес сети: 192.168.1.1

Comment: контрольную решаете?

Comment: помоги    11